# How to convert an array containing arrays to only hold one array

Tags: python

My issue is this. I have an array like this :

```
test = array([[1],[2],[10] .... [-5]])
```

I want to be able to just convert this to an array that looks like this

```
test = [1,2,10,..., -5]
```

The test is a numpy array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use reshape() to change the array into 1D array as:

```
import numpy as np
test = np.array([[1],[2],[10],[-5]])
test=test.reshape((test.shape[0],))  # test.shape[0] gives the first dimension (the number of rows)
# reshape changes test array to one dimensional array with shape (test.shape[0],) 
print(test)
```